# Best way to write a Gradle task that can be customised from the command line?

Tags: gradle

I want to provide defaults for my properties, but allow them to be overridden from the command line in a relatively easy way.
I'm using Gradle 1.0 Milestone 3.

This is what I've got, it works pretty much the way I want but it's quite verbose.  It just doesn't seem very Gradle-ish - as opposed to the actual work I'm doing, where 150-odd lines of Java code have compressed down to about 2 lines of gradle script.

```
task sbtCopyTask  {
  fromProp = "defaultCopyFrom"
  toProp = "defaultCopyTo"

  overrideFromProp = System.getProperty('fromSysProp')
  if( overrideFromProp != null && !overrideFromProp.trim().empty ){
    fromProp = overrideFromProp
  }

  doLast {
    println "copying ${fromProp} to ${toProp}"
  }
}
```

executing

```
$GRADLE_HOME/bin/gradle sbtCopyTask
```

results in:

```
copying defaultCopyFrom to defaultCopyTo
```

and executing

```
$GRADLE_HOME/bin/gradle sbtCopyTask -DfromSysProp="wibble"
```

results in:

```
copying wibble to defaultCopyTo
```

- I know there's a copy task build into Gradle - the question I'm asking is "how do I write a build script that is customisable from the command line".
- I tried the "-P" command line option - doesn't seem to do what I want.
- I want to be able to do this from the command line, properties files or environment variables would be inconvenient.

**Edit:**
Doh, 10 seconds after posting - this seems kind of obvious.

So, this works fine and is completely good enough for me (unless there's a better way?)

```
fromProp = System.getProperty('fromProp', 'defaultFromProp')
```

Comment: There is an alternative that looks like `System.properties.get('prop', 'defaultValue')`. Not that it's any better))